# Transactional Replication Log Reader Error cannot execute sp_MSAdd_ReplCmds

Tags: sql-server

I am attempting to add stored procedure articles (replicating the execution) to an existing publication and immediately after adding them the Log Reader agent fails with the message "Cannot execute sp_MSAdd_ReplCmds at {Distribution Server}" and then another error message with "Error Converting nvarchar value '.' to int.   When troubleshooting I made the following findings:

1. Creating a new publication on other distribution servers with the same articles and with similar subscriptions is successful.
2. Creating a new publication on the same distribution server in another distribution db with similar subscriptions is successful.
3. Creating a new publication on the same distribution server and the SAME distribution db is fine until I add a single subscription, then the log reader fails with the same error
4. If you remove the offending articles the log reader error goes away but in one case the error persisted prompting a rebuild of the publication
5. I have seen other errors discussed on the web involing sp_MSAdd_ReplCmds but the subsequent error messages usually clue one in to permissions errors that can be resolved by making the agent owner and other accounts involved in replication the sysadmin.  In my case, all involved accounts are sysadmins already.  I have not been able to find anything that involves this strange conversion error.

   The distribution server is MS SQL Server 2012, and while we believe the distribution db was newly created after our upgrade to SQL Server 2012, it is possible the db was migrated from SQL 2008.

   Reconfiguring or reinitializing all the publications involved on this server to add these articles would be a long long task which I am trying to avoid.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We solved the problem.  I post it here in case others run into this as well.  The lesson learned is not to trust a script created from an existing replication object.  In order to create a new stored proc execution article in a different distribution db, I scripted from an existing article, changed the relevant parameters and executed it.  Our DBA removed four parameters included in the generated script for adding the article - @destination_table, @pre_creation_cmd, @creation_script, and @description.  They seemed like default values in there, but keeping them out altogether prevented the log reader error discussed in the OP.  Not sure which one actually was the solution - we removed all 4 and then it worked.  I've had problems in the past when generating scripts from existing replication objects that didn't accurately reflect the object itself, and so this is yet another reason to be wary of scripting from existing replication objects.